# Integer function with Datediff in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to add a new column in Spotfire so I can get the age of the person in years.
This is the function used:

```
Integer(DateDiff(Date(2018,3,31),Date([Y_BIRTH_DATE],[M_BIRTH_DATE], [D_BIRTH_DATE])))/365
```

However, the computed column returns as `(Empty)`.
If I run the expression without the `Integer()` and the `/365` the function returns the appropriate number of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `Days` :

```
Days(DateDiff(Date(2018,3,31),Date([Y_BIRTH_DATE],[M_BIRTH_DATE], [D_BIRTH_DATE])))/365
```

Explanation : your result is a timespan, so it cannot be converted to integer. The `Days` function will extract the integer value of the timespan.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the previous answer solved your problem, but I'm including an alternative solution for others with similar questions.

You're currently calculating the age of a person in years by taking the number of days that the person has been alive up to some point in time (3/31/2018 in your example), and then dividing the number of days by 365, which will result in a Real number, such as 28.6 years.

By dividing by 365, your example doesn't take Leap Years into account.  This may not be an issue for you, but it might be for another user.

The following expression will

1. Return the number of years as a real number (e.g. 28.6), as does
   yours
2. Account for leap years in its calculation

   ```
   DateDiff("year", 
            Date([Y_BIRTH_DATE],[M_BIRTH_DATE], [D_BIRTH_DATE]), 
            Date(2018,3,31))
   ```

Note that I've formatted the expression so every one of the DateDiff function's arguments has its own line.  Obviously, the expression could be collapsed to a single line, I just did it to improve clarity.

Also, the example provided in Spotfire for the DateDiff function has the earliest of the two Dates being passed as the first Date argument, and the later Date being passed as the second Date argument. It's become my habit to do so, as well, so that's the order in which I've placed your Date arguments in my example.